# How to call print function RadEditor Control without using print button of RadEditor?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me how to call RadEidtor built in print with javascript ? Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You will need to obtain a reference to the editor:

```
var editor = $find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");
```

and then fire the event like so:

```
editor.fire("Print");
```

Comment: I test your code but it is this different Html lay out , when i print wtih RadEditor built in Print function.Can u how me another way.Thank u.

Comment: The fire method executes the same command as is executed when clicking on the Print button on the toolbar. See: [fire()](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-fire.html). From the above link: `The command name represents the name of the tool as it is specified in the inner <telerik:EditorTool tag, in the codebehind or in ToolsFile.xml.`. If you find this is producing different results then you should consult Telerik as according to the documentation this should not be the case.